# Choose Sentences with x High Score and Save to the Same Row (Dataframe)

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have Dataframe ranked_sentences like this

```
       0              1
0   0.093305    Hello this is a
1   0.088413    Hello this is b
2   0.091036    Hello this is c
3   0.095541    Hello this is d
4   0.092201    Hello this is e
5   0.088338    Hello this is f
6   0.089100    Hello this is g
7   0.089980    Hello this is h
8   0.088446    Hello this is i
9   0.092737    Hello this is j
10  0.090902    Hello this is k
```

i want to choose sentences with sn (sn=4) high score and save in list. moreover, a sentence order according to index. I want the output like this:

```
                                    x
0   Hello this is a. Hello this is d. Hello this is e. Hello this is j.
```

anybody can help me to get my goal. I try with this code, but i confused for get sentences with high score. thank you

```
d = []
sn = 4
for i in range(sn):
    summary = ranked_sentences[1][i] 
    d.append(summary)
    print(summary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code will

1. sort the dataframe on column 0 in descending order.
2. Fetch top 3 rows.
3. Convert the 3 values of column 1 to a list
4. Assign the list to list d.

```
d = ranked_sentences.sort_values(0, ascending = False).head(3)[1].to_list()
```

Comment: it's work, but i make mistake at my questions. i am sorry, i want choose a sentence order according to index. like this `Hello this is a. Hello this is d. Hello this is e. Hello this is j`

Comment: You should add sort_index to sort it on index like this. d = ranked_sentences.sort_values(0, ascending = False).head(3).sort_index()[1].to_list()